# Passthrough indentification in wcf

Tags: wcf, identification, passthru

How do I pass the identity of the logged on user in an a webapplication to a service beeing called by the webserver?

My idea her is to set som kind of EndpointIdentity on the cahnnel. In my case this will be an GUID identifing the user's session on the webserver.

Anyone got any exprience on this.. Maybe I have misunderstood the concept?

Any idea's or links would be apriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have replied to one of the questions on Stackoverflow for a similar kind of problem:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771535/how-to-pass-wcf-username-clientcredentialtype-to-other-service/2454013#2454013)

Please check, it will be helpful for your problem also.